# How can i posistion text in div?

Tags: html, css

I need to position a percent of load bar to center for horizontal and middle for vertical, it appears is not correct. This is my code:

```
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: #CCC;">
     <div style="width: 40%; height: 50px; background-color:#0C0;"></div>
     <span>50%</span>
</div>
```

And [**the jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/skXU6/).

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately vertical-align is not for aligning vertically the children, but to align the element respect to its siblings. Here's a great tutorial with many alternatives to how to do it: [Themeforest](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

Comment: Here its http://jsfiddle.net/skXU6/

Comment: What is the actual desired result?

Comment: I want like this http://jsfiddle.net/skXU6/2/
 but when green bar is over 50% it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a combination of things...

1. You should take the green element out of the document flow by giving it `absolute` positioning.
2. You should use the `line-height` property to shift the text into a vertically central position.
3. Negotiate any layering issues with the `z-index` property.

So your HTML would become this:

```
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: #CCC;">
 <div style="position:absolute; width: 60%; height: 50px; background-color:#0C0;"></div>
 <div style="position:relative;z-index:1;line-height:50px">50%</div>
```

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skXU6/4/).

Comment: When a green bar is over than 50%, It conceals text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'line-height' css property to vertically align the text inside the div.
The 'line-height' property should be set to the height of the div.
For example:

line-height: 50px;

See if it works.